# how to turn the flattenObj function from the ramda cookbook into an iterative function

Tags: object, recursion, flatten, ramda.js

I'm dealing with a test environment nodejs/sequelize/mocha/chai.
I find this [flattenObj](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#flatten-a-nested-object-into-dot-separated-key--value-pairs) extremely useful
when testing objects, generated by sequelize for instance.
It makes those structures digestible for chai and the results become more concise
Too bad it's implemented in a recursive way :( .
Especially in Javascript this spells doom, as there is always a call stack limit lurking.
Hacks like wrapping the recursive function in a setTimeout doesn't seem to work for me and are kind of ugly.
I'm currently trying to figure out to rewrite it in an iterative way, but that's quite a brain teaser, at least for me.
Dealing with while loops inside a ramda function doesn't feel right.
Is there a way of doing this in a call stack friendly way without breaking ramda conventions?

```
const go = obj_ => chain(([k, v]) => {
  if (type(v) === 'Object' || type(v) === 'Array') {
    return pipe( 
        tap(console.log),            
        map(([k_, v_]) => [`${k}.${k_}`, v_]) 
     )(go(v))
  } else {
    return [[k, v]]
  }
}, toPairs(obj_))

const flattenObj = obj => {
  return fromPairs(go(obj))
}

flattenObj({a:1, b:{c:3}, d:{e:{f:6}, g:[{h:8, i:9}, 0]}})

{
  "a": 1,
  "b.c": 3,
  "d.e.f": 6,
  "d.g.0.h": 8,
  "d.g.0.i": 9,
  "d.g.1": 0
}
```

this works as expected, but it breaks down causing a call stack exceeded error, because of the recursive go function, when the object becomes too complex.
This would be super useful if it's applicable on more complex structures as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad thing that it's implemented in a recursive way.  That's the best way to deal with recursive data structures such as JS objects.

But you can always convert recursive solutions to iterative ones if you want to manage your own stack.  Here's a fairly ugly approach, but which seems to work for that simple test case:

```js
const flattenObj = (obj) => {
  const results = [];
  const steps = Object.entries(obj)
  while (steps.length) {
    const [key, val] = steps.splice(0, 1)[0]
    if (typeof val == 'object') {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(steps, Object.entries(val).map(
        ([k, v]) => [key + '.' + k, v]
      ))
    } else {
      results.push([key, val])
    }
  }
  return results.reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: v}), {})
}


const foo = {a:1, b:{c:3}, d:{e:{f:6}, g:[{h:8, i:9}, 0]}}

console.log(flattenObj(foo))
```

This will not work with cyclical structures, but the cookbook version would not have either, presumably.

I wrote this originally using some Ramda functions (`toPairs` in place of `Object.entries`, `is(Object, val)` in place of `typeof val == 'object'` and `return fromPairs(results)` in place of `return results.reduce(...)`.)  But with all the mutation going on (`splice` and `push`), it feels a very unRamda-ish solution, and I removed them.  (Ramda functions, you understand, don't want to be associated with gauche mutability!)

I don't know if this will solve your problem.  I've only used `flattenObj` a few times, although I can see the utility in tests.  But it strikes me that if this is causing recursion problems, cyclical data structures are a more likely issue than actual depth.  But of course I don't know your data, so who knows?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
As I was digging deeper into my problem I realized that dumping a sequelize ORM data structure with JSON.stringify(obj,null,2) 
is no where near the original source. 
The original source is literally an endless stream of data.
I thought I was testing a pure JSON dump as well, but I couldn't reproduce the call stack error.
In the meantime I've found the [dot-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-object) module, which is way ahead of any pure ramda version.
But I also had a general interest in knowing on how to de-recursify a ramda function.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to write test cases around an endless stream of data!